# Does zero cost arbitrage imply the existence of negative cost arbitrage?

Tags: no-arbitrage-theory

I've been wondering, if there exists a zero-cost arbitrage trading strategy in some market, does that also mean that there also has to be a negative-cost arbitrage trading strategy in the same market?

I did a small experiment with a simple market of two assets, the riskless one and a risky one, in a binomial tree setting. It seems that, if you are allowed to buy/short fractional amounts of either asset it is always possible to engineer a strategy in which you have negative initial outlay and positive payoff later (even if it is a worse strategy than the zero-cost strategy).

Scenario 1: Bond is cheaper than the Stock

1. Short the stock, Invest proceeds (negative cost)

Scenario 2: Stock is cheaper than the Bond

1. Borrow slightly more money than you need, buy the stock with almost all of the money.(negative cost)

However, I'm not really sure this small example covers all scenarios. If my observation is true, how should I approach verifying it in a more rigorous manner?

Comment: What is "negative cost arbitrage" ?

Comment: In this case, I am using the term "negative cost arbitrage" to refer to arbitrage strategies where the initial cost is negative - that is, you get some cash upfront for executing it. This is in contrast to zero-cost arbitrage in which the initial net cashflow is zero.

Comment: If you can create an arbitrage profit in period 1 with no money up front **and** if you can issue a risk free security in period 0 (backed by the period 1 cash) then you can create a cash up front arbitrage. But in a model where there are no risk free securities (no borrowing/lending) then the two kinds of arbitrage are not equivalent.